# xcode 6 crash when control + drag uielement to ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I try to control + drag/drop a UIButton on my ViewController, Xcode crashes. It works when I add an Action connection but not with Outlet connection.

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6C131e
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): +[IDESwiftSourceCodeGenerator isTeardownCounterpart:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x11ef36778
```

I got no problem if I do it in a new project.
I'm using xcode 6.2 on OSX 10.9.5.

Comment: you may have some issues configuring the build settings...

Comment: what can I confugure? Can you say me where to look please?

Comment: Have you restarted Xcode?  Have you restarted your computer?

Comment: Yes I've tried several times...